# AADSTS50020 User account 'xxx@zbc.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'xx-xx-xx-xx' Error in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, azure, winforms

I need to implement `AAD B2C Authentication` in `C# Winforms` Application.

I have **Registered** My app in `Azure AD B2C` in **portal.azure.com** with `User Flows(Sign up and sign in, Password Reset, Profile Editing)`, also I have added the user `xxx@zbc.com` and in the App Authentication I have added the **`Platform` "Mobile and desktop applications"**

I am using the following code in my `Login` Screen.

```
string ClientId = "9xXxXxXx-7XxX-4XxX-9XxX-aXxXxXxXxXxX";
string Tenant = "exXxXxXx-9XxX-4XxX-XxX-8XxXxXxXxXxX";
IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;

PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                            .WithRedirectUri("https://aaa.xxx.com/oauth2/nativeclient")
                            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                            .Build();
string token = PublicClientApp.UserTokenCache;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var _scopes = new string[] { "user.read" }.AsEnumerable();
      var authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                    .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

While I am running the code I am getting the Popup for sign in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYT8p.jpg)

I have entered the Email then Next entered the Password while click on Sign in it is telling `Wrong Password`. Then I have reset the password from the same page and tried to `Sign In` again. Now new error message like...

```
AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@zbc.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in 
tenant 'XXX' and cannot access the application '9xXxXxXx-7XxX-4XxX-9XxX-aXxXxXxXxXxX'(XXX) 
in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. 
Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account. c# winforms
```

Please give me a solution for this issue...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: There are several moving parts to b2c and its easy to get wrong. If you are following a tutorial start again ,double check everything

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have done it several times the same process, but failed. I don't know how to do. please suggest me any tutorials of some options to do...

Comment: Is the user an external user ?

Comment: Yeah it is an External user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this Problem,
Need to change the Manifest file,

Go to **`Azure AD B2C --> App Registrations --> Choose your App --> Manifest`**
in the Json,
Change value of **`oauth2AllowImplicitFlow`** to **`false`**

Go to **`Azure AD B2C --> App Registrations --> Choose your App --> Authentication`** add your redirect URL as `https://<TenentName>.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient`

in C# application Set the Variables like

```
string Domain = "<TenentName>"; //replace with your own tenant name
string lPolicySignUpSignIn = "<Signin/Signup Policy Name>";
string lPolicyEditProfile = "<Edit Profile Policy Name>";
string lPolicyResetPassword = "<PasswordReset Policy Name>";
string RedirectUrl = "https://<TenentName>.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient";
string ClientId = "9xXxXxXx-7XxX-4XxX-9XxX-aXxXxXxXxXxX";
string Tenant = $"{Domain}.onmicrosoft.com";
string AuthorityBase = $"https://{Domain}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
string[] Scopes = new string[] { "https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/webapi/read_policies" };
string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{lPolicySignUpSignIn}";
string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase}{lPolicyEditProfile}";
string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase}{lPolicyResetPassword}";
string PolicySignUpSignIn = lPolicySignUpSignIn;
string PolicyEditProfile = lPolicyEditProfile;
string PolicyResetPassword = lPolicyResetPassword;
```

Policies can be set in, Go to **`Azure AD B2C --> User flows`** click on `+ New user flow` button and create for those three policies one after another.

Add the below function and call it from Sign In Button of your application.

```
private async Task<int> aadValidation()
{
    string lsObjectID;
    try
    {
        var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync(PolicySignUpSignIn);
        authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .ExecuteAsync();
        if (authResult == null)
        {
            authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                              .ExecuteAsync(); //await LoginTest();
            if (authResult == null)
            {
                return 0;//Failed
            }
        }
        lsObjectID = authResult.Account.HomeAccountId.ObjectId; //Returns the object id of the user who is trying to sign in
        if (lsObjectID == "" || lsObjectID == null)
        {
            return 0;//Failed
        }
        return 1;//Success
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                .ExecuteAsync(); //await LoginTest();
            if (authResult == null)
            {
                return 0;//Failed
            }
            
            lsObjectID = authResult.Account.HomeAccountId.ObjectId; //Returns the object id of the user who is trying to sign in
            if (lsObjectID == "" || lsObjectID == null)
            {
                return 0;//Failed
            }
            return 1;//Success
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            return 0;//Failed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Error states that the account "xxx@zbc.com" is not part of the AAD Tenant (XXX) in which the application is registered.

xxx@zbc.com -Also from the error - the users appears to be live account (@outlook.com,@hotmail.com etc)

So to resolve this -

Login into the tenant(XXX) in which you've registered the application.

Add your live account (xxx@zbc.com) to the tenant as an external user.

You could refer the below article for the detailed steps on adding the external account

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops

Alternatively, you could change the application to support accounts outside your tenant (XXX)

[image]

Currently, From the error - I assume your configuration is set to **Accounts in this organizational directory only**

You will have to change it to the third option :  **Accounts in any organizational directory**

This can be changed Azure -> Azure Active Directory -> Manage -> App Registrations --> AppName -> Supported Account Types

[image]

You could refer the below link for detailed steps :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-modify-supported-accounts

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think I have done this step but still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I too am experiencing the same thing, would love to know the right way to correct this.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue. From what I've seen, it appears this issue occurs when the same e-mail address is used for an AAD account (in another tenant) and also as a Microsoft/Live account, however when adding external users there is no way to distinguish and it doesn't support both.